# is switch(true) {... valid javascript?

Tags: javascript, boolean, switch-statement

I recently came across code where a switch statement seemed reversed with the answer (boolean) in the switch and the expressions in the case. The code ran fine as intended but I'm concerned about cross browser. Is it valid javascript?

```
switch(true) {
  case (y < 20):
    //
    break;
  case (y < 60):
    //
    break;
  case (y < 130):
    //
    break;
}
```

Comment: I came across this in PHP as well and changed it to an if/else if block. In my opinion, someone was being too clever in that just because you can doesn't mean that you should. But each to their own.

Comment: While it's perfectly good code switch (true) in my opinion it's bad practice, it has a high chance of causing side effects like multiple matching cases where only the first 1 gets executed or people actually calling functions in cases. If you need a switch true, in my opinion, you most likely need to rethink your code because it's probably written too complex. (which is clearly visible in your example)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This snippet is perfectly fine. It's just another way of expressing:

```
if (y < 20) {
    // ...
} else if (y < 60) {
    // ...
} else if ( y < 130) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would express the equivalency in terms of `if (true == (y < 20))`, etc, to show what switch is *really* doing. For instance, if it was `switch(false)` it would be equivalent to `if (false == (y < 20))` and yield different results.

Comment: @pst I wrote "another way of expressing" not "is the exact equivalent to".

Comment: Hence why I wrote "I would express [it] in terms of" and not "that is wrong" - don't take a comment as such a bad thing. (Although my comment *is* wrong; `===` semantics are used and not `==`)

Comment: `s/elseif/else if/`.  `elseif` is PHP, not JS. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's valid.

As in many "modern" languages, the `switch` in Javascript is very far from the original int-based `switch` from the C language, it only keeps the general semantics.

The switch clause, as normalized in ECMAScript, is explained here in details : http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11

Basically, the first case whose value is equal to the expression in `switch(Expression)` is executed.

The main advantage over the obvious `if else if` sequence is the ability to ommit the `break` statement and execute more than one block. Note that, contrary to the old C switch, there is no real performance improvement and in this case it's neither more succinct nor more readable.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for JavaScript but the `As in many "modern" languages` part is not correct. Most compiled application require the case value to be a constant, i.e can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: I didn't speak of constants but of int. Examples : java (now accepting strings), Go (which is compiled), Ruby.

Comment: Let's add C#, too. In Go the case clauses don't have to be constants at all.

Comment: In C# the case must be a constant value. I'm pretty sure java is the same. For the rest, I wouldn't say two languages are many.

Comment: I never said they shouldn't be constants... Please read the answers you comment before commenting.

Comment: The answer reads as though you're saying many modern languages are the same as JavaScript which isn't the case if JavaScript allows expressions in the case.

Answer (score 7):

The [syntax of switch statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11) is:

> ```
> SwitchStatement :  
>   switch ( Expression ) CaseBlock  
> CaseBlock :  
>   { CaseClauses(opt) }  
>   { CaseClauses(opt) DefaultClause CaseClauses(opt) }  
> CaseClauses :  
>   CaseClause  
>   CaseClauses CaseClause  
> CaseClause :  
>   case Expression : StatementList(opt)  
> DefaultClause :  
>   default : StatementList(opt)
> ```

No where it says that switch expression or the case expression has to be a number, string, boolean or anything. `true` is perfectly acceptable as a switch expression and `y < 20` is perfectly acceptable as case expression. Keep in mind that comparison between switch expression and case expressions are made using `===` operator.

In the code you posted, the first `true` case will be executed until `break` is encountered or the switch block ends.

Answer (score 2):

#### The cases will get executed based on value of `y`.

Because the conditions depend on the value of `y`. As said by [aefxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264395/aefxx), it is an other form of:

```
if (y < 20) {
    // ...
} elseif (y < 60) {
    // ...
} elseif ( y < 130) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: no, that's incorrect. the first break will jump to the end of the switch!

Comment: @bukfixart Updated the answer. Cases gets executed based on y!

Comment: @bukart actually, no. the first break would need to be inside a case block that actually executes. a break is a statement that only applies when you actually hit it. hence you can say `if (x<y) break;` now if x>=y, the break will never have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

It is valid.

The code

```
switch(f0()) {
    case f1(): ..; 
    case f2(): ..;
    default: dflt;
}
```

where `fX()` represents *an arbitrary expression* (a function invocation is used to show forced evaluation) can be approximately re-written as

```
for (;;) { // for "break"
    var _x = f0()
    if (_x === f1()) { .. }
    if (_x === f2()) { .. }
    dflt;
    break;
}
```

That is, **the expression in the `case` is *evaluated* and then compared with the expression in the `switch`**. (This is a sharp divergence from languages like C or Java that require constant values in the `case` expressions.)

Of course, the `break` will "exit the switch" - as opposed to the standard fall-through semantics - and as such, where `true` is the expression supplied to `switch`, the posted example is semantically equivalent to the `if/else if` as shown by aefxx.