# switch method returns only default value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to handle multiple conditions for date format in my app and using for this purposes switch method. The function looks well but the problem is that nothing from my cases' conditions doesn't work. I understand that something wrong with condition but cannot understand what exactly.

Could anybody tell me where my mistake is?

```
 var dateSettings = function (value) {

        var timezone = localStorage.getItem('timezone');
        timezone = JSON.parse(timezone);

        var timeFormat = localStorage.getItem('timeFormat');
        timeFormat = JSON.parse(timeFormat);

        var dateFormat = localStorage.getItem('dateFormat');
        dateFormat = JSON.parse(dateFormat);

        switch( value ) {
            case (timezone === true && timeFormat === true && dateFormat === false):
                return value = moment.utc(value).format('MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm');

            case (timezone === true && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === false):
                return value = moment.utc(value).format('MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss');

            case (timezone === false && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === false):
                return value = moment(value).format('MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss');

            case (timezone === false && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === true):
                return value = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

            case (timezone === false && timeFormat === true && dateFormat === true):
                return value = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

            case (timezone === true && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === true):
                return value = moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

            default:
                return value = moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
        }
    };
```

Comment: You should not use switch case like that.... If you are going to have checks, use if/else if/else....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch-case` is not the same as `if-else` statements - this is what you actually should use.

The `case` has to depend only on `value`.

Have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

```js
function switchCase(expression) {

    switch(expression) {
        case "a":
            console.log("This is an A");
            break;
        case "b":
            console.log("This is a B");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("DEFAULT");
    }
}

switchCase("a")
switchCase("banana")
```

Also you return an assignment `return value = ...` which is not good style in my eyes.

Better do:

```
value = 4;
return value;
```

This your sample the way I would do it:

```
var dateSettings = function(value) {

   var timezone = localStorage.getItem('timezone');
   timezone = JSON.parse(timezone);

   var timeFormat = localStorage.getItem('timeFormat');
   timeFormat = JSON.parse(timeFormat);

   var dateFormat = localStorage.getItem('dateFormat');
   dateFormat = JSON.parse(dateFormat);

   if (timezone === true && timeFormat === true && dateFormat === false) {
       value = moment.utc(value).format('MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm');
   } else if (timezone === true && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === false) {
       value = moment.utc(value).format('MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss');
   } else if (timezone === false && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === false) {
       value = moment(value).format('MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss');
   } else if (timezone === false && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === true) {
       value = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   } else if (timezone === false && timeFormat === true && dateFormat === true) {
       value = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
   } else if (timezone === true && timeFormat === false && dateFormat === true) {
       value = moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
   } else {
       value = moment.utc(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
   }
   return value;
};
```

Comment: Yeah, it works great. I just thought that I can replace this statement with switch method

Comment: You can.  It's just a little odd:  `switch (true) {case (test1): expr1; break; case(test2): expr2; break; ...`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118996/is-switchtrue-valid-javascript

Comment: @ScottSauyet Cool, did not know this - but it's kind of uncommon.