# Why I can't do with Switch-Case what I do with If-Else in JS?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, switch-statement, dom-events

Can you help about the JS DOM example below,

The **if-else structure** I specified in example 1 works, but the **switch-case structure** I specified in example 2 does not work.
The **switch-case structure** does not work, although they both function the same. Why ?

Thanks

--- Example 1 / Works ---

```
fontSizes.forEach(size => {
 
    size.addEventListener('click', () => {
      
        if(size.classList.contains('font-size-1')) {
            .....
        } else if (size.classList.contains('font-size-2')) {
            .....   
        }
        
    })
})
```

--- Example 2 / Doesn't work ---

```
fontSizes.forEach(size => {
 
    size.addEventListener('click', () => {
      
      switch (size.classList.contains) {
           case 'font-size-1': 
             ....
           break;
           case 'font-size-2': 
             ....
           break;
       }            
    })
})
```

Comment: "although they both function the same". They certainly do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please not that they are not the same. In the first one you are calling function add taking the output whereas in the second one all you are passing via switch statement is the reference to function. The `size.classlist.contains` is a function which expects an argument. Please know the difference.

Comment: Thanks. That sentence was enough for me to understand the difference between the two.

> The `size.classlist.contains` is a function which expects an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the `switch` properly, you're checking `size.classList.contains` which points to a function with strings (like `font-size-1`) instead of comparing the actual value.

You can use `split` (with the `includes` functions) or use `size.classList.contains` in each case

Take a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains
[How to check className in a switch statement when an element has multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983030/how-to-check-classname-in-a-switch-statement-when-an-element-has-multiple-classe)

Answer (score 1):

`contains` is a method.

So you **can't** use:
`switch(size.classList.contains){case 'class1':...}`

Instead you should use `if(size.classList.contains('class1')){}`

If you want a more clean code, you can create an array (or object) for the cases and put `if`s on a loop.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I thought I could handle things more easily with the switch case structure instead of the if else structure. But now I understand the difference better :)