# Explain switch (true) Narrowing in typescript 5.3

Tags: typescript, switch-statement

Can someone explain `switch (true)`  Narrowing in typescript 5.3 ?

Quote from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-3.html#switch-true-narrowing , I just don't get how this has improved narrowing type in the old way.

Writing `switch (true)` also feels quite strange.

```
function f(x: unknown) {
    switch (true) {
        case typeof x === "string":
            // 'x' is a 'string' here
            console.log(x.toUpperCase());
            // falls through...
        case Array.isArray(x):
            // 'x' is a 'string | any[]' here.
            console.log(x.length);
            // falls through...
        default:
          // 'x' is 'unknown' here.
          // ...
    }
}
```

Without `switch (true)`  I can write my code like the following, so falls through maybe one advantage for switch case, even if it is, it is offset by writing `switch (true)` (in my opinion)

```
function f(x: unknown) {
     if (typeof x === "string") {
            // 'x' is a 'string' here
            console.log(x.toUpperCase());
            console.log(x.length);
     }
     else if  (case Array.isArray(x)) {
            console.log(x.length);
     }
     else {
          // 'x' is 'unknown' here.
          // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: All the information is in the notes "*now can perform narrowing based on conditions in each case clause within a switch (true)*" This wasn't possible before 5.3:  [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFADwFyPAazHAdzAEpEBvAKEWsQGcCYoIALRFKAJxAFNTKaBiCAENa3RFACeAB25xgiNIgC8qxACJanGGADm6jFUHGA9CcQByNBcQxaiYZa0cdum824duR4wIgJaOAAbbgA6ILhddFCoOABVaVkOAGFRbhRiYgBuH19qM2RhIKD7KGYOOBBdZlDa3L80xABBDg5hSVC7FrbJdGJDPIECqxs7BydtPUQAHwcwSQBtAF13TzD6338wQJDwyOiQvTLsjdNzYCKSiXLK6trQ08QAE24LkCCoAcHh61t7C1w+CIqy8D0GiAK91yAF8KNCgA)

Comment: It's still explained in the notes. Previously it wasn't possible. Now it is. The fact that you could write it different to the same effect only serves to show it was a missing feature. If your question is "why would I write it like this", then it's just a personal choice. Nobody is making you. But it's a logic chain that is equivalent to another logic chain. Yet one worked, the other didn't.

Comment: The fallthrough is *not the feature that is being highlighted*. The `case` statements with narrowing is. Is your question then about the example that was supplied, not with the feature?

Answer (score 1):

**In a sentance, `switch` statement is like asking which of the following cases are equal to my condition? In your example, that would mean "which of the following cases equal `true`?".**

Try thinking about a generalised `switch` statement:

```
switch (a) {
  case x:
    break;

  case y:
    break;

  default:
}
```

In essence, this will compare statement `a` to each `case`. I.e: does `a` equal `x`? If not, does `a` equal `y`? If not, check next case.

Code might be easier to reason with if you rewrite the whole `switch` statement to an `if - elseif - else` statement.

```
    if (true == (typeof x === "string")) {
            // 'x' is a 'string' here
            console.log(x.toUpperCase());
    } else if (true == Array.isArray(x)) {
            // 'x' is a 'string | any[]' here.
            console.log(x.length);
    } else {
          // 'x' is 'unknown' here.
          // ...
    }
```

The only difference between your `switch` and `if-elseif-else` is that `switch` will fall through all the cases that match the condition until `break` is reached, while `if-elseif-else` cases are exclusive of each other.

Comment: Basically, I have said in my question that fall-through is the "advantage" I see here.

Answer (score -1):

I did a little research. The `switch (true)` pattern is my main confusing point as I said in my question fall-through may be one advantage. Then I see this [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#an_alternative_to_if...else_chains) (emphasis mine):

> The `switch (true)` pattern as an alternative to `if...else` is
> **especially useful if you want to utilize the fall-through behavior**.
>
> ```
> switch (true) {
>   case isSquare(shape):
>     console.log("This shape is a square.");
>   // Fall-through, since a square is a rectangle as well!
>   case isRectangle(shape):
>     console.log("This shape is a rectangle.");
>   case isQuadrilateral(shape):
>     console.log("This shape is a quadrilateral.");
>     break;
>   case isCircle(shape):
>     console.log("This shape is a circle.");
>     break;
> }
> ```

So that is one example I want to use this new narrow type way instead of [the old ways](https://byby.dev/ts-type-narrowing).

About `switch (true)` also refer to [is switch(true) {... valid javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118996/is-switchtrue-valid-javascript)